# Kendo UI and templates : bind value with an observable model and the source with and external datasource

Tags: templates, mvvm, kendo-ui

I'm using MVVM and templates with Kendo UI.
I would like my template contains a dropdown with the binded value of my model and ***with an external datasource***.

My observable object looks like that :

```
data : {
    comments : "any comments here...",
    nested_object_array : [
        {id:0, name:"name_0", nested_value:"20"},
        {id:1, name:"name_1", nested_value:"21"},
        //...
    ]
}
```

I would like my template look like this :

```
<script id="global-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <span Data-bind="text: comments"></span>    
</script>

<script id="sub-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <input data-role="dropdown" data-source="--here an external source--" data-bind="value: nested_value" />
</script>
```

Is it possible ? If yes, how to do that ?

Comment: Hi Bobby, many thanks for your answer. I didn't try it for now. I will give you feedback as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Following example seems to cover it quite clearly - [here](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/dropdownlist/mvvm.html) :

Template:

```
<script id="sub-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
      <input data-role="dropdownlist"
                       data-auto-bind="false"
                       data-text-field="ProductName"
                       data-value-field="ProductID"
                       data-bind="value: selectedProduct,
                                  source: yourexternaldatasource,
                                  visible: isVisible,
                                  enabled: isEnabled"
                       style="width: 180px"
                />
</script>
```